# Vue template processing: How to remove trailing spaces between text node and closing tag

Tags: vue.js, vue-loader

In my `vue-cli` project i have many `.vue` files with tags that have trailing spaces between text node and closing tag. I need that trailing spaces (or tabs, or line breaks).

What i have in my template:

```
<RouterLink
  :to="{name: 'vacancy', params: { id: vacancy.id }}"
  class="vacancy-name-link"
>
  {{ vacancy.title }}
</RouterLink>
```

What i want:

```
<a href="/vacancy/0">Vacancy title</a>
```

What i have:

```
<a href="/vacancy/0"> Vacancy title </a>
```

Why i can't write code in one-line:

1. there is a rule in eslint **vue/multiline-html-element-content-newline**
2. in a project i have many files (*more than 500*) with that issue with many different tags (e.g. `<span>`, `<a>` etc.)

Is there any method to update rendered template to trim trailing spaces inside tags?

Sorry for my english.

Comment: hi, have you found a solution? I have the same problem, though in the Nuxt + Vue dev